# Python OOP - calling a methode in a class

Tags: python, oop

I am new in Python OOP and I am trying to understand one line of this Code
(This is just a part of the whole Code)

I am trying to understand what "pet.name" in the methode "whichone" do.
The parameter 'petlist' in whichone can be empty or a list with strings.
The Parameter 'name' has just one string.

Can someone explain me what "pet.name" actually do?

```
from random import randrange

class Pet():
    boredom_decrement = 4
    hunger_decrement = 6
    boredom_threshold = 5
    hunger_threshold = 10
    sounds = ['Mrrp']
    def __init__(self, name = "Kitty"):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = randrange(self.hunger_threshold)
        self.boredom = randrange(self.boredom_threshold)
        self.sounds = self.sounds[:]  


def whichone(petlist, name):
    for pet in petlist:
        if pet.name == name:
            return pet
    return None # no pet matched

def play():
    animals = []

    option = ""
    base_prompt = """
        Quit
        Choice: """
    feedback = ""
    while True:
        action = input(feedback + "\n" + base_prompt)
        feedback = ""
        words = action.split()
        if len(words) > 0:
            command = words[0]
        else:
            command = None
        if command == "Quit":
            print("Exiting...")
            return
        elif command == "Adopt" and len(words) > 1:
            if whichone(animals, words[1]):
                feedback += "You already have a pet with that name\n"
            else:
                animals.append(Pet(words[1]))

play()
```

Comment: The parameter `petlist` must be a list of `Pet`

Comment: What's your python version?

Comment: *The parameter 'petlist' in whichone can be empty or a list with strings.* are you are about that latter? If not try to call `whichone` with 1st argument being `list` of `str`s and observe what would happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `petlist` parameter is a `List` of `Pet` objects, then the `for pet in petlist` line will iterate through the list and you will be able to use the `pet` variable to access the current element.

What is happening in the for loop is that you check whether the current object has the name you passed as a second parameter of the `whichone` function. To do this, you'll need to access the `name` attribute of the object stored in the `pet` variable (which is assumed to be of type `Pet`). The Python syntax for this is `pet.name` (`<variable_name>.<attribute_name>`).
You know of the existence of this attribute thanks to the class definition, to the `__init__` method, where you can see the new instance of the Pet class will receive a name upon creation (which is defaulted to "Kitty").

Comment: I wasn't aware that petlist is a List of Pet objects. I thought it is a List of str.
How can I see that it is a List of Pet objects?
I mean in the function play(), you can see "animals = []". So for me it seems just a empty list.

Comment: You can partly verify it where the function is used. Here the only occurrence of this function is `whichone(animals, words[1])` with `animals` being declared as a List (`animals = []`) and having only `Pet` instances added into it (the only occurrence of elements being put in `animals` is `animals.append(Pet(words[1]))`.

Comment: You can also reason the other way around and ask yourself "What can it be?" and look at the `whichone` function. By analyzing it, you can deduce that the `petlist` argument needs to be a List (because of the use of a `for` loop). Also, the elements that are in the List must have a `name` attribute (because the `pet.name` syntax means that you are accessing the `name` attribute of the variable, which here is an element of the list. As you will go through all the elements in the list, they all must have this attribute). In theory, this could be a list of anything that has a `name` attribute

Comment: Additionally, you generally try and be coherent with your variable names when writing a program. In this case, `petlist` is pretty self-explanatory. (Don't take the name as a proof of what this is, errors are made, but this can generally be a strong indicator)

Comment: Has your question been answered? If it is the case, you might want to mark it as solved.

Comment: Yes, it has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

Each `Pet` has a name that you give when constructing an object, that being `pet.name` ("Kitty" by default).

I assume `whichdone()` is supposed to get a list of `Pet` objects and query them against `name` argument. It will return the first `Pet` whose name matches a `name` that you've used as input to `whichdone()`.